# How to fix this error? FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: python, visualization, anytree

My code is like this:

```
from anytree import Node, RenderTree
from anytree.exporter import DotExporter

udo = Node("Udo")
marc = Node("Marc", parent=udo)
lian = Node("Lian", parent=marc)
dan = Node("Dan", parent=udo)
jet = Node("Jet", parent=dan)
jan = Node("Jan", parent=dan)
joe = Node("Joe", parent=dan)
for pre, fill, node in RenderTree(udo):
    print("%s%s" % (pre, node.name))

DotExporter(udo).to_picture("udo.png")
```

I am getting an error like this. If I use to_dotfile instead of to_picture, it creates the dot file. I want this to_picture function to work. How do I fix this error?

```
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-2a66170e009d> in <module>
     12     print("%s%s" % (pre, node.name))
     13 
---> 14 DotExporter(udo).to_picture("udo.png")

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\anytree\exporter\dotexporter.py in to_picture(self, filename)
    266             dotfile.flush()
    267             cmd = ["dot", dotfilename, "-T", fileformat, "-o", filename]
--> 268             check_call(cmd)
    269         try:
    270             remove(dotfilename)

~\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py in check_call(*popenargs, **kwargs)
    340     check_call(["ls", "-l"])
    341     """
--> 342     retcode = call(*popenargs, **kwargs)
    343     if retcode:
    344         cmd = kwargs.get("args")

~\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py in call(timeout, *popenargs, **kwargs)
    321     retcode = call(["ls", "-l"])
    322     """
--> 323     with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
    324         try:
    325             return p.wait(timeout=timeout)

FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Comment: check if the file exists or not

Comment: Make sure `udo.png` this file exits, where you are running your `.py` file

Comment: I am trying to create udo.png file in this code. @prashantrana

Comment: I am trying to create udo.png file in this code. @shaikmoeed

Comment: Check this [doc](https://anytree.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/anytree/exporter/dotexporter.html#DotExporter.to_picture). To know how to use `.to_picture()`.

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me just to install graphviz

https://graphviz.org/download